# TypeScript + Vue: Loading static json configuration when opening index.html

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on an app that requires an API key to be inserted into the config.

Since I'm using `npm run build` to generate a static page (dist folder with index.html that loads `app.js` and appropriate chunks and styles) - the config file gets read only once and then embedded into generated `app.js`.

Due to how it works, whenever I change values in the non-embedded config (available in the `dist/public/` folder - the values don't refresh in `app.js` as they should.

Is there any way to import config dynamically whenever `index.html` along with attached `app.js` reload?

Here's what I tried:

```
import * as config from '../public/finnhub.config.json';

const stockProvider = reactive(new FinnhubStockProvider(config));
```

It does load the config - but only during the build, meaning it's constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing the config file would cause it to be bundled. If you want the config file to be read on demand instead, you could `fetch` it:

```js
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const config = ref({})

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('/finnhub.config.json')
      config.value = await resp.json()
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      fetchData()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, just a point of note: this only works when you host the static files and not run index.html in your browser as a file. (double click index.html).

Comment: For that wouldn't you just need to run the same func on document load, no?